# Matrix.solve() gives different answer with RationalFunction than with Rational

Tags: java, linear-algebra, jscience

I'm using the *Jscience* linear algebra module to solve a linear system of rational numbers. This works as expected and gives the correct result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DenseMatrix<Rational> m = DenseMatrix.valueOf(
        DenseVector.valueOf(r(1, 1), r(-1, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(1, 1), r(0, 1)),
        DenseVector.valueOf(r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(1, 1), r(-1, 1), r(0, 1), r(2, 1)),
        DenseVector.valueOf(r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(-1, 1), r(1, 1)),
        DenseVector.valueOf(r(1, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1)),
        DenseVector.valueOf(r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(1, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1)),
        DenseVector.valueOf(r(0, 1), r(-1, 1), r(1, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1)));

    DenseVector<Rational> v = DenseVector.valueOf(r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(1, 1), r(1, 2));

    Vector<Rational> sol = m.solve(v);

    System.out.println(sol);
}

private static Rational r(int n, int d) {
    return Rational.valueOf(n, d);
}
```

The code will print `{0/1, 1/6, 2/3, 1/1, 1/6, 1/6}` when executed.

My intention is to solve this system with many different values of one of the components of `v`, so I converted the code to use `RationalFunction<Rational>` instead of `Rational`. In the first step, I've not introduced a `Variable` yet and every `RationalFunction<Rational>` is a constant. My understanding is that this should give the same result as before:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DenseMatrix<RationalFunction<Rational>> m = DenseMatrix.valueOf(
        DenseVector.valueOf(r(1, 1), r(-1, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(1, 1), r(0, 1)),
        DenseVector.valueOf(r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(1, 1), r(-1, 1), r(0, 1), r(2, 1)),
        DenseVector.valueOf(r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(-1, 1), r(1, 1)),
        DenseVector.valueOf(r(1, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1)),
        DenseVector.valueOf(r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(1, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1)),
        DenseVector.valueOf(r(0, 1), r(-1, 1), r(1, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1)));

    DenseVector<RationalFunction<Rational>> v = DenseVector.valueOf(r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(0, 1), r(1, 1), r(1, 2));

    Vector<RationalFunction<Rational>> sol = m.solve(v);

    System.out.println(sol);
}

private static RationalFunction<Rational> r(int n, int d) {
    return RationalFunction.valueOf(Polynomial.valueOf(Rational.valueOf(n, d), Term.ONE), Polynomial.valueOf(Rational.ONE, Term.ONE));
}
```

But this prints the following when executed, i.e. `0/0` for each component:

```
{([0/1])/([0/1]), ([0/1])/([0/1]), ([0/1])/([0/1]), ([0/1])/([0/1]), ([0/1])/([0/1]), ([0/1])/([0/1])}
```

Does `Matrix.solve()` actually support using `RationalFunction`? It did work when I tested it with a one-by-one matrix.

Where should I look next to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [rational function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function), the coefficients of the component polynomials can be taken from any [field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29), including rational numbers. A `RationalFunction<Rational>` reflects this usage, but `solve()` never evaluates the function defined by each matrix entry.

One approach would be to construct a new matrix in which each entry is set to the result returned by `r.evaluate()`. In effect, you would convert the problem in your second example to one that could be solved as shown in your first example.

Comment: Do I understand this right: For each value for the variables in the `RationalFunction`s, `solve()` will find a solution, if it exists, but it will refuse to find a solution that is correct for all values of the variables? The second example does not contain a variable, which may be misleading of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: In your second example, `solve()` concatenates the operations that it normally uses to decompose a matrix of rational values. Examine the result of `r.evaluate()` for each element of `sol` to see the effect.

Comment: For each element `sol.get(i).evaluate()` throws an exception: `java.lang.ArithmeticException: Dividend is zero`.

Comment: Exactly; the stack trace shows the accumulated operations. You're asking `solve()` to find a vector of ration functions that meets the `solve()` contract; it can't.